# How to get background color of a container to cover the entire width of the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to html/css and to practice I'm trying to build a portfolio webpage. I have two containers as seen in the image, and I'd like to get rid of the space on the side when changing the background color. I tried messing around with padding and margin to no avail.

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

[image]

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: ;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

.container {
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.nav {
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.nav>li>a {
  padding: 0px !important;
  color: black;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.header .nav {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.supporting h1 {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
}

.supporting .container {
  background-color: white;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

.work .container {
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(225, 225, 225, .8)
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <h1 class="logo">header</h1>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Photography</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">blog</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="supporting">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>hi.</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="work">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>work</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: i see no image, actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `.container` bootstrap gives it a specific `width`.
You have two choices there, 
first you can use `.container-fluid` instead of `.container` and that will make full width container (you just need to remove some padding).

Secondly you can choose to wrap `.container` inside a `.container-fluid`

```
<div class = "container-fluid">

    <div class ="container">
        content goes here
    </div>

</div>
```

and then in your `css` you give background color to `.container-fluid` not to `.container`

```
div.container-fluid{

    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: ok, was able to achieve it but had to use !important. i've been told that is really recommended to use.

Comment: @user8473431 NO you should not use !important that's why i added a 'div' before .container-fluid to create a stronger css selector than bootstrap. And i think that you are making something wrong your css file or css code should be after you inlcude bootstrap link

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check bootstrap documentation about [container-fluid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#overview-container) this is the bootstrap way to manage full width containers.